# How to use sprite as font in Unity?

Tags: unity, javascript, sprites, unityscript

I've started working on my first game in Unity; It's very simple, there's a spinning block in the middle, and there are spinning blocks coming from all sides. When they hit the middle block, you lose a life. You have 3 lives. I've hit a bit of a brick wall, here, though; I can't seem to find anywhere how to use a sprite atlas as a font, or at least be able to sprite my own font. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need fancy texture in your fonts, Unity supports True Type fonts, so you can render your text easily using the [GUI system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html) (for instance, drawing a [Label](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/gui-Controls.html)).

In order to use Bitmap fonts you'll have to write the code yourself to translate the characters into sprites, or use one of the libraries available, like [NGUI](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140) or [Daikon Forge](http://www.daikonforge.com/dfgui/).

Comment: Thanks, I was going to use a sprited font, just cause it fit better, but I decided it looked fine the way it was anyway. I thought unity had a BMF thing in in, but I guess I was wrong.